# htaccess rewrite rule for multiple pages

Tags: .htaccess

this seems so simple, but it's not working for me. 
I am trying to have both show.php?id=$1 and producer.php?id=$1 rewrite as friendly URLs. 
The first one works perfectly, the second does not. If I remove the first, the second works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

My code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /show.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /producer.php?id=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite simple.

You cannot have more than one rewrite rule for the same directory, you would need to have a separate folder for each IE. have a folder called "show" and have the htaccess file that contains the rewrite data for show.

.htaccess for show folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /show.php?id=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Then have another folder called "producer" with the 2nd rewrite rule.

.htaccess for producer folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /producer.php?id=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you. So I would need to move show.php and producer.php to a folder? That seems like a lot of restructuring of my site.

Comment: Yes, if you wanted the "friendly" url's you asked about. The rewrite condition basically eliminates the /producer.php from the URL. Think of it as when you go to http://yoursite.com/45 with the rewrite rule applied you would be going to http://yoursite.com/show.php?id=45 no matter what you type in the browser as the rewrite rule just takes the first condition. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help, but it's not fun as the site is already built and templated. This will cause me a bit more work. Thanks though, at least I dont have to bang my head against a wall anymore.